# Return to same state of the activity from another activity on pressing back

Tags: java, android

I have implemented a search feature in **Activity_A**. On hitting the search query it displays the results in a tabular form. I have made few table cells as clickable. On clicking a cell, **Activity_B** is launched which displays some more information. But when i go back, my search results are gone. I have been following [android official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack), but its kind of overwhelming for  a beginner like me to completely follow.

I want to return to the same state of **Activity_A**(that is, having the search results in place) after pressing back navigation from **Activity_B**. Here is a snippet from **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
<!-- The MainActivity (it has no parent activity) -->
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Activity_A: A child of the MainActivity -->
    <activity android:name=".Activity_A"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/activity_display_message">
        <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
        <meta-data
             android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
             android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <!-- Activity_B: A child of the Activity_A -->
    <activity android:name=".Activity_B"
        android:parentActivityName=".Activity_A"
        android:label="@string/individual_record">
        <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Activity_A" />
    </activity>
```

Here is the code snippet for Activity_A where a intent is created and Activity_B is started.

```
someTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent Activity_B = new Intent(Activity_A.this, Activity_B.class);
            startActivity(Activity_B);
        }
    });
```

Is there a decent way to make this happen?. Although this question might get marked as duplicate as there are many questions targeting the same, but i'm not able to find a correct solution for it.

Comment: Can you share the code where you are switching activities?

Comment: @BilalNaeem, made edits.

Comment: When you go back you're supposed to get back to the previous state. Share both of your Activity_A and Activity_B

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why its changing the state. It should retain the state how you left it.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you're a beginner, It might be worth checking out [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) if you haven't read up on them yet as they're more recommended than using multiple Activites (depending on your application). The [FragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager) class makes navigating between Fragments really easy too as it also keeps the state of the Fragments for you.

Comment: Have to try it. Have no ideas how to proceed.